# postgresql insert on conflict triggers attempted to delete invisible tuple error

Tags: postgresql

i am sometimes seeing the following error in my logs when inserting the same data twice:

```
error: attempted to delete invisible tuple
    at Connection.parseE (/home/ubuntu/vacation-server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/ubuntu/vacation-server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:381:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/vacation-server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:117:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
```

my query is as follows:

```
    INSERT INTO google_places (
      id,
      data,
      geographic_coordinates
    ) VALUES (
      $1,
      $2,
      ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-118.440908 34.063246)', 4326)
    )
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
      SET data = EXCLUDED.data,
        geographic_coordinates = EXCLUDED.geographic_coordinates,
        date_updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    RETURNING *
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In versions before 9.5.5, upserting TOASTed data can raise this exception in certain specific circumstances. I ran into it with a conflict key based on a function index (specifically `ON CONFLICT (md5(myblob)) DO UPDATE`), but it's the same error.

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.database.pgsql-bugs/dJJ_ZozKmbY) from the mailing list has the full details. The bug has been fixed in 9.5.5 and 9.6, but I don't know of any easy workaround for earlier versions of Postgres. I ended up having to use an old-style CTE upsert.

Comment: Actually, this is fixed in 9.5.5 (see the release notes) and 9.6.0, see the [commit message](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1baAqv-0001LO-RX@gemulon.postgresql.org). You might want to update the answer.

Comment: ah thanks. i am using 9.6 in production and locally, which is why i never see the error in production. but circleci is still on 9.5, which is the only place i see the error.